# Bluetooth pairing with different devices

Tags: bluetooth

I have 2 bluetooth devices (BT1, BT2) and 2 bluetooth receivers (R1, R2). Their behaviors are differents, i'd like to know why.
BT1 is a BT speaker (UE BOOM 2)
BT2 is a mouse (tecknet BM306)

Initially, BT1 and BT2 are not paired to R1 and R2.

1) To pair BT1, I click on BT1 "connect" button

2) On R1, I look for available BT devices, and BT1 appears. I do the pairing.

3) Now I want to use BT1 on R2 so I click again on "connect" button, and pair BT1 to R2.

4) Now I want to use BT1 on R1 back. BT1 is already associated to R1, so I can select BT1 without doing the pairing again.

With BT2, this is a bit different. At 4), when I want to use BT2 on R1 after BT2 was paired with R2, then it doesn't work and I need to click on the "connect" button again.
It seems something special happens when using BT2 connect button, old paired  receivers do not recognize the device anymore.

To make it simple, each time I want to use BT2 on another device, i need to click on the connect button, even if it was already paired in the past, which is not the case with BT1.

Is that normal and is there something to do to keep the pairing on all receivers?

Comment: What type of device are BT1 and BT2? Are they the from the same vendor, or the same model? Did you pruchase them approximately at the same time? *(note: edit your question to add these infos)*

Comment: Infos added in descriotion

Comment: Thanks. From this additional info, I'd say the behavior you observed is normal. Each vendor can define their own strategies regarding to Bluetooth pairing, depending on what makes sense for them.